# I can't use a property for my project's parent version despite described as such in Spring Cloud doc

Tags: maven, spring-boot, pom.xml, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-config

In Spring Cloud Config documentation, `pom.xml`'s parent configuration is presented with a version variable `spring-boot-docs-version` as such [1](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-config/multi/multi__quick_start.html#_client_side_usage):

```
   <parent>
       <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
       <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
       <version>{spring-boot-docs-version}</version>
       <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
   </parent>

<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
            <version>{spring-cloud-version}</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-config</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

So I added the following in my `pom.xml`'s properties:

```
<properties>
    <spring-boot-docs-version>2.1.8.RELEASE</spring-boot-docs-version>
    <spring-cloud-version>Greenwich.SR3</spring-cloud-version>
</properties>
```

But it doesn't seem to work; even by prefixing the `{spring-boot-docs-version}` expression with `$` doesn't make maven resolve the parent POM.

Note however that I had to add this extra `$` in the `<dependencyManagement>`:

```
<version>${spring-cloud-version}</version>
```

I searched the Spring Boot documentation too, but only found out it's not using a variable [2](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/using-boot-build-systems.html#using-boot-maven-parent-pom):

```
<!-- Inherit defaults from Spring Boot -->
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.8.RELEASE</version>
</parent>
```

How to use such a variable in these (external) parents' `<version>`tag?

Note: I also read that if you don't inherit from one of these starters, you'll loose some maven pre-configuration (like plugins & so.)

Comment: That's a bug in the docs

Comment: @spencergibb which means? The variable's name is wrong?

Comment: There was a failure in our docs release process. `{spring-cloud-version}` should be `Greenwich.SR3`. There is no property support. `{spring-boot-docs-version}` should be `2.1.8.RELEASE`.

Comment: OK. Then it's a maven limitation probably. Should I open an issue to report this "bug" in the doc? Or will it be fixed somehow?

Comment: I already opened one

Comment: Following up on your question about `$` usage, it's a _required_ prefix on Maven `property` references, as described at [Maven POM Properties](https://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Properties).

Comment: @SeanMickey I know that, it was just to put this in regard with what the Spring doc showed. But even with the `${ }` I can't make it work in the `<parent>` tag. Why is that?

Comment: I just went  back to look over your question and I don't see anything obviously out of place. What's the relationship(s) between the POMs that you 'd like to include in your scope of shared property values?

Comment: And if there is actually _NO_ relationship between them, you also have the option of placing property values in one of your `Maven` `settings.xml` files. -- To make the property values available across a group of unrelated `mvn`  builds / projects.

Comment: In fact, `spring-boot-starter-parent` is the parent POM of my project because it's a starter, that's the recommended way to inherit all the configuration (dependencyMgmt & plugins & so) for a Spring Boot project; it was just a matter of grouping versions into the `<properties>` tag, rather than having them scattered all around my pom.xml, but seems like it's not possible that way for the parent's version. I also found out you can use `${revision}` since Maven 3.5 in order to have the same version but that's useful only when you control both projects (parent & child)...